# React onDrop function for a task manager

Tags: javascript, react.js

This a working function as part of a drag and drop task manager im playing around with. The function is working fine, but it just looks messy and long to me. I haven't added all the code as I'm looking just to tidy up the function itself. I have added the state though as guidance.

**function**

```
onDrop = () => {

  let people = [...this.state.people]
  let newPeopleArray = []
  let newChoresArray = []
  let personToUpdate = {}

  people.forEach( person => {
    if ( person.name !== this.state.targetPerson ) {
      newPeopleArray.push(person)
     } else {
      personToUpdate = person
      personToUpdate.chores.forEach( chore => {
          if ( chore !== this.state.targetChore ) {
          newChoresArray.push(chore)
        }})
      personToUpdate.chores = newChoresArray
    }})
 newPeopleArray.push(personToUpdate)
 this.setState ({ people: newPeopleArray})
}
```

**state**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {

    targetChore: '',
    targetPerson: '',

    people: [
    { name: 'Grace', chores: ['clean kitchen', 'wash dog', 'laundry']  },
    { name: 'Sam', chores: ['walk dog', 'wash car', 'go shopping']  },
    { name: 'Rose', chores: ['wash windows', 'vaccum', 'clean bathroom'] }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I update my question let me know what you think about it . I prefer object oriented programming

Comment: Thanks @FabrizioBertoglio, its an interesting take and a completely different method which is interesting! I need to explore OOP more. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. I find Object Oriented programming is easier to refactor and mantain, as it already iherints properties from real world objects .. It is easier to copy something from the real world instead of re-inventing everything

Answer (score 1):

A `Person` class encapsulates the attributes/methods and logic for the `Person` object. Currently inherits from `Object`, but you can at any time extend this logic by creating an new super class or children and distribute the logic between those hierarchies.

```
class Person extends Object {
    constructor(props) {
       super
       this.name = props.name
       this.chores = props.chores
    }

    addSubject() {
      if (this.isFound) { return new People().push(person) }
      // your choice to either create a chore class or write some subroutine
      else { person.chores.forEach( chore => chore.addChore ) }
    }

    // either pass targetPerson as param or add it to the Person object as attribute
    isFound() { this.name !== this.state.targetPerson }

}
```

```
people = [ new Person('Grace', 'clean kitchen', 'wash dog'..), etc..]
```

I also believe the `onDrop` subroutine should just have the responsibility of `dropping person` or `returning` a new `people` object. It would be an `instance method` of the `People` class

```
class People extends Object {
    drop = () => {
      this.each( person => person.addSubject() )
      // etc...
    }

}
```